# openpyxl convert scraped data in time format

Tags: time, openpyxl

I would like to convert the data scraping from an internet site, regarding the time, the data is extracted like this (for example 9:15) and inserted into the cell, I would like at the bottom of the column to make the total of the hours, the problem I would like python to convert it to numerical format so that I can add it up.
any idea?

```py
def excel():
    # Writing on a EXCEL FILE
    filename = f"Monatsplan {userfinder} {month} {year}.xlsx"
    try:
        wb = load_workbook(filename)
        ws = wb.worksheets[0]  # select first worksheet
    except FileNotFoundError:
        headers_row = [
            "Datum",
            "Tour",
            "Funktion",
            "Von",
            "Bis",
            "Schichtdauer",
            "Bezahlte Zeit",
        ]
        wb = Workbook()
        ws = wb.active
        ws.append(headers_row)

    wb.save(filename)
    ws.append(
        [
            datumcleaned[:10],
            tagesinfo,
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
        ]
    )
    wb.save(filename)
    wb.close()

excel()
```

Comment: Use `datetime.strptime()` to convert strings to dates or times.

Comment: Your code shows opening/creating a spreadsheet and inserting two values from somewhere else. I think your code sample is missing the loop which gets the data and calls `excel()`. When you get to the end of that loop, then you'd want to insert the summary. Or a formula to calculate it in Excel…

Answer (score 0):

You should split the data you scrapped.

```
time_scrapped = '9:15' 
time_split = time_scrapped.split(":")  
hours = int(time_split[0])
minutes = int(time_split[1])
```

Then you can place it in separate columns and create formula at the bottom of the column.